# PHP Regex to find a substring from a big string - Matching start and end

Tags: php, regex, simple-html-dom

I want to find title of pages from a huge haystack but that do not have any class or unique id, so i can't use DOM parser here, i am aware i must use regular expressions. 
Here is example of what i am trying to find:

```
<a href="http://example.com/xyz">
    Series Hell In Heaven information
</a>
<a href="http://example.com/123">
    Series What is going information
</a>
```

Output Should be an array with

```
[0] => Series Hell In Heaven information
[1] => Series What is going information
```

All series titles have start with Series and end with **information**. from a huge string of multiple things i only want to extract titles. 
Currently i am trying to use a regex but its not working, here's what i am doing right now.

```
$reg = "/^Series\..*information$/";
$str = $html;
preg_match_all($reg, $str, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

I don't know much about making regular expressions. Help would appreciated. Thanks

Comment: remove this literal dot `\.` and the ancors,  all you need is this `/Series.*information/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 preg_match_all('/(Series.+?information)/', $str, $matches );
```

As

https://regex101.com/r/oJ0jZ4/1

As I said in the comments, remove the literal `\.` dot and the start and end anchors...  I would also use a non-greedy require any character. `.+?`

Otherwise you could match this

```
Seriesinformation
```

if the casing of Series or information may change such as

Series .... Information

Add the `/i` flag as in

```
     preg_match_all('/(Series.+?information)/i', $str, $matches );
```

The outer capture group isn't really needed, but I think it looks nicer with it in there, if you just want the variable content without the Series or Information then move the capture `( )` to that bit.

```
 preg_match_all('/Series(.+?)information/i', $str, $matches );
```

Note you'll want to `trim()` the match because it will likely have spaces at the beginning and end or add them to the regx like this.

```
 preg_match_all('/Series\s(.+?)\sinformation/i', $str, $matches );
```

But that will exclude matching `Series information` with one space.

If you want to be sure you don't match over an information such as

```
[Series Hell In Heaven information Series Hell In Heaven information]
```

Matching all of that you can use a positive lookbehind

```
preg_match_all('/(Series.+?(?<=information))/i', $str, $matches );
```

Conversely, if there is a possibility it will contain two information words

```
   <a href="http://example.com/123">
        Series information is power information
   </a>
```

You can do this

```
    preg_match_all('/(Series[^<]+)</i', $str, $matches );
```

Which will match up to the `<` as in `</a`

AS a Side note you could use the PHPQuery library ( which is a DOM parser ), and look for an `a` tag that contains those words.

https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery

And

https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/wikis/Manual.wiki

Using something like

```
  $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a:contains('Series)")->text();
```

This is an excellent library for parsing HTML

Comment: up for more possibilities. Also you can refer non-greedy as 'lazy' ;)

Comment: Yea I think if it's greedy there is possibility to capture too much content if there is another information in there, best bet would be to use a positive look behind. as in `(Series.+?(?<=information))`

Comment: Sure, I've done a TON of webcrawler, scraper stuff.  Check out PHPQuery if you need more functionality then a regx can provide.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$str = '<a href="http://example.com/xyz">
    Series Hell In Heaven information
</a>
<a href="http://example.com/123">
    Series What is going information
</a>';
preg_match_all('/Series(.*?)information/', $str, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

the capture will be in $matches[2].
Basically your regex does not match because of the `\.`.

[EDIT]

If you need also the words `Series` and `information`, then you don't need to capture just do `/Series.*?information/` and found matches in $matches[0].

Comment: Dito, Upvote for you .. however my comment was first :-P

Comment: Yes it's fair :) I was giving the answer and you commented shortly first haha. (while posting we don't see page new posts). As you added more details - which i was doing to but then too late - you deserve points ;)